# Are the following sentences grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Are the following sentences grammatically correct?

1. The destiny is not changing even we want that.
2. Unavoidable destiny by God is the truth we cannot change it.
3. The actions we take sometimes determine our destiny .

Comment: Hi Sdg, If you simply provide a sentence and ask whether it's correct, that's proof reading, and ELL doesn't do proof reading. Please identify specific concerns about each sentence, and then we can help to answer your concerns. it might also help if you explain what the sentences are intended to mean.

Comment: The actions we take sometimes determine our destiny .Imean the structure of sentence is it right and sound understanding to native speaker

Comment: @Sgd, This site is for people who want to improve their english, so we expect people to do a bit of homework before asking questions. We are not a free proofreading service.  Please identify **specific** concerns about each sentence. What words do you think are unclear: what grammatical constructs do you think might be incorrect? https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please

Comment: I want to know the right usage of the sentence, for example, No. The destiny is not changing even we want that, why not the destiny won't changing even we want that. the difference between is not changing and will not changing